# How can i use tensorflow object detection to only detect persons?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

I've been trying to use tensorflow's object detection to try and set up a decent presence detection. I'm using tensorflow's pretrained model and a code example to perform object detection on a webcam. Is there any way to remove objects from the model or filter out objects from the person class?
This is the code i currently have.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90


# ## Download Model

if not os.path.exists(MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'):
    print ('Downloading the model')
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
    for file in tar_file.getmembers():
      file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
      if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
        tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
    print ('Download complete')
else:
    print ('Model already exists')

# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

#intializing the web camera device

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Running the tensorflow session
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
   ret = True
   while (ret):
      ret,image_np = cap.read()
      image_np = cv2.resize(image_np,(600,400))
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

      b = [x for x in classes if x == 1]
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.

      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(b).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      #print (len(boxes.shape))

      #print (classes)

      final_score = np.squeeze(scores)    
      count = 0
      for i in range(100):
          if scores is None or final_score[i] > 0.5:
                  count = count + 1
                  print (count, ' object(s) detected...')

#      plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
#      plt.imshow(image_np)
      cv2.imshow('image',image_np)
      if cv2.waitKey(200) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          cap.release()
          break
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw that you used a filter in the line `b = [x for x in classes if x == 1]` to just get all the person detections. (In the label map, person's id is exactly 1). But it didn't work because you need to change `boxes`, `scores` and `classes` accordingly.  Try this :

Firstly remove the line

```
b = [x for x in classes if x == 1]
```

Then add the following after `sess.run()` function

```
boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
scores = np.squeeze(scores)
classes = np.squeeze(classes)

indices = np.argwhere(classes == 1)
boxes = np.squeeze(boxes[indices])
scores = np.squeeze(scores[indices])
classes = np.squeeze(classes[indices])
```

and then call the visualization function

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      boxes,
      classes,
      scores,
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
```

The idea is the model can produce detections of multiple classes but only class person is chosen to visualize on the image.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the input! My reputation is to low to give you an upvote though :(

Comment: I had faced the same problem that mentioned in this question, could anyone check this link and reply with a valuable solution?

Comment: This solution helped me alot. Altough there are other ways of detecting wether or not there are persons on the image. 
`# Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label. scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0') classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')`
 In these lines of code an array will be stored inside scores and classes. In classes will be the classes this model detects. In scores, the percentage that match each class. You can then iterate trough those two to find your desired class and the matching score.

Comment: feel free to ask more if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

> When the detected class is the only one, 
>   I suggest this method to prevent loss of array.

```
# Select specific class
boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
scores = np.squeeze(scores)
classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)

indices = np.argwhere(classes == 1)
boxes = np.squeeze(boxes[indices], axis=1) # to prevent errors made by nd.array of size 1 nd.array
scores = np.squeeze(scores[indices], axis=1)
classes = np.squeeze(classes[indices], axis=1)
```